# Won't count digits apart from letters, won't count spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the problem, it just takes in characters... but I wanted to separate them. count spaces and digits ext. Edit { "space" ment; [spacebar] blank space between words, (" ").

```
def main():
    sen = (input(' Type something: '))
    printStats(sen)

def printStats(input):
    print('Statistics on your sentence: ')
    print('   Digits:', digit(input))
    print('   Spaces:', space(input))


def digit(input):
    count = 0
    for digit in input:
        count +=1
    return (count)

def space(input):
    count = 0
    for space in input:
        count +=1
    return (count)

main()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
def digit(input):
    count = 0
    for digit in input:
        count +=1
    return (count)
```

All this does is count the number of *characters* in your string.  It is identical to `len(input)`. (note that you should not call variables `input`, that masks a python built-in function)  Your `space` function does the same thing, since it is the same function with renamed local variables.

If you want to fix the above functions, you need an `if` statement in your `for` loop that checks for `.isdigit()` and `.isspace()`, respectively.

For `space`, at least, you should really instead be using the `.count()` method of strings.

```
a = 'this is my string'

a.count(' ')
Out[11]: 3
```

Your approach is fine for `digit` (if you implement some `if` logic in your loop).  Or there's the list comprehension approach, `sum(c.isdigit() for c in my_string)`.